# fetch the array having specific value

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have the json array value which have age and number.I want to create a new set of array which has `{"num":2}` in it (ie)need to return `[{"age":2,"num":2},{"age":3,"num":2}]`

```js
var array_val='[{"age":1,"num":1},{"age":2,"num":2},{"age":3,"num":2}]';
console.log(array_val);
function fetchList(array_val) {
    return array_val = {"num":1};
}
array_val.filter(fetchList)
console.log(array_val);
```

Comment: take `JSON.parse` before using the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 issues in your code:

1. You don't parse your string to JSON
2. You have a wrong filter
   function

```js
var array_val='[{"age":1,"num":1},{"age":2,"num":2},{"age":3,"num":2}]';
console.log(array_val);

function fetchList(array_val) {
    return array_val.num === 2;   // return only records whose num is 2
}

// here you parse string into JSON and apply the filter
var data = JSON.parse(array_val).filter(fetchList);

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var fetched_object = array_val.filter(function(obj) {
  return obj.num == 1;
});
```

Note: Like @NinaScholz said you need to [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) the string so it is an array.

Answer (score 1):

You need parse the JSON string [`JSON.parse()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwje0qegoMfVAhVJto8KHUvsB78QFggtMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FJSON%2Fparse&usg=AFQjCNHkowMNeO8CgweprUJz3xDY9HxuPQ) .And matching condition was wrong .`num` is the inner propery of the object .so you need to match `a.num == 2` .Don't forget to add `==`

```js
var array_val='[{"age":1,"num":1},{"age":2,"num":2},{"age":3,"num":2}]';
console.log(array_val);
function fetchList(a) {
    return a.num == 2;
}
var res = JSON.parse(array_val).filter(fetchList)

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```js
var array_val=JSON.parse('[{"age":1,"num":1},{"age":2,"num":2},{"age":3,"num":2}]');
console.log(array_val);
function fetchList(array_val) {
    return array_val.num == 2;
}
array_val = array_val.filter(fetchList)
console.log(array_val);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work instead:

var requiredValue = array_val.filter(function(item) { return item.num === 2; 
});

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var array_val=JSON.parse('[{"age":1,"num":1},{"age":2,"num":2},{"age":3,"num":2}]');
var newarr =[]

for(let i of array_val){
if(i.num == 2){
newarr.push(i);
}

}

console.log(newarr);
```